# How to Parse JSON Data returned with Braces

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, asmx

I'm making a query to an ASMX Webservice that should be returning current user data from a database.  In the return I'm getting correctly returned data, however each time I parse the jSON; I am receiving errors on the data.
I've posted my jQuery Call and the Return from the WebService.

I've strinified it, still not able to parse the data...it seems to be complaining about the surrounding braces.

========================
**ASMX PSEUDO**
========================

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public String GetLDAPUser(string sam)
{
    ArrayList objs = new ArrayList();
    string sql = @"***SELECT USERS FROM AD THROUGH OPENQUERY***";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(VMDATA))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            //Parameters
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sam", sam);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read()) 
                { 
                    objs.Add(new
                    {
                        Name = reader["Name"],
                        Login = reader["samAccountName"],
                        Mail = reader["Mail"],
                        DistinguishedName = reader["distinguishedName"],
                        DisplayName = reader["displayName"],
                        GivenName = reader["givenName"]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs);
}
```

========================
**jQuery CALL**
========================

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/apps/Webservices/wsUsers.asmx/GetUser",
        data: "{'user': 'jwg1'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = data.d;
            console.log(obj);
        }
    });
});
```

========================
JSON DATA
========================

```
[
  {
    "Mail": "joe.garrett@rineco.com",
    "samAccountName": "jwg1",
    "distinguishedName": "CN=Joe Garrett,OU=obfuscated,DC=com",
    "givenName": "Joe",
    "displayName": "Joe Garrett",
    "Name": "Joe Garrett"
  }
]
```

Comment: why not do var obj = data.d[0]?

Comment: Yes, I've done this and thought the same thing...the object becomes undefined if I reference it based on the thought that is an actual object.  At present, it seems to be an index reference of the string rather than an actual jsonObject.  (i.e. doing the above returns "[" on the first index for example.

Comment: if it is a string JSON.parse(data) should create an obj

Comment: That Solved it...btw. Sometimes, the simplest things can really throw a curve ball at you.  In fact the content return was not an object and the parse worked.  var obj = JSON.parse(data.d); then obj[0]["Mail"] is populated...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in depperm's comment, you likely want to do

```
var obj=data.d[0];
```

This will allow you access its values by doing

```
obj.Mail
```

or

```
obj.Name
```

etc.

I'm not sure why your data is coming back with the outter brackets[], if the JSON will only ever have 1 member, consider eliminating the []. Then your current code will work more effectively.

Comment: I've considered it...however, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented) is returning the data with the braces automagically.

Comment: Because `objs` is an `ArrayList`. You're adding to it in a loop, so it could potentially have more than one object in it.